# Multidimensional numerical integral giving wrong answer

Tags: numerical-integration, integral-transforms

I am reducing a series of atomic transition amplitudes using Gaussian transforms (that allow one to combine all coordinate dependence into a single quadratic form so that one can complete the square and integrate) and want to check intermediate results using numerical integration. In the simplest nontrivial case of a 3D integral of a pair of Yukawa potentials, one with a shifted coordinate r2 (with the azimuthal angle integral done and u=Cos[theta] ),

```
    NIntegrate[(1/(E^(eta1*r1)*r1))*
    (Exp[(-eta2)*Sqrt[r1^2 - 2*r1*r2*u + r2^2]]/
     Sqrt[r1^2 - 2*r1*r2*u + r2^2])*r1^2*2*Pi, 
    {u, -1, 1}, {r1, 0, Infinity}] /. {eta1 -> 3, eta2 -> 5, r2 -> 7}
```

the resultant value 8.50761*10^-11 matches the analytic result,

```
    N[(4*(-E^((-r2)*eta1) + E^((-r2)*eta2))*Pi)/
    (r2*(eta1^2 - eta2^2)) /. 
   {eta1 -> 3, eta2 -> 5, r2 -> 7}]]
```

.
When I introduce the Gaussian integral representation of the first Yukawa potential (I. S. Gradshteyn and I. M. Ryzhik, Table of Integrals, Series, and Products (Academic, New York, 1980), p. 307, Nos. 3.325, 5ed p. 337),

```
    NIntegrate[
   ((1/Sqrt[Pi])*(1/(E^(eta1^2/(4*rho1))* Sqrt[rho1]))*
     (Exp[(-eta2)* Sqrt[r1^2 - 2*r1*r2*u + r2^2]]/
      Sqrt[r1^2 - 2*r1*r2*u + r2^2])*r1^2*2*
     Pi)/E^(rho1*r1^2), {u, -1, 1}, {r1, 0, Infinity}, 
   {rho1, 0, Infinity}] /. {eta1 -> 3, eta2 -> 5, r2 -> 7}]
```

all is well.  But when I introduce the Gaussian representation of the second Yukawa potential,

```
    NIntegrate[((1/Sqrt[Pi])*(1/(E^(eta1^2/(4*rho1))*Sqrt[rho1]))*
     (1/Sqrt[Pi])*(1/(E^(eta2^2/(4*rho2))*Sqrt[rho2]))*r1^2*2*Pi)/
    (E^(rho1*r1^2)*E^(rho2*(r1^2 - 
        2*r1*r2*u + r2^2))), {u, -1, 1},{r1, 0, Infinity}, {rho1, 0, 
    Infinity}, {rho2, 0, Infinity}] /. {eta1 -> 3, eta2 -> 5, r2 -> 7}
```

I get a bad answer for this 4-dimentional integral, 7.71785*10^-12. I have tried
`Method -> {"AdaptiveMonteCarlo", "MaxPoints" -> 10^n}` for various values of n,
`Method -> {"GlobalAdaptive", "SingularityDepth" -> n}` for various values of n,
`Method -> "DuffyCoordinates"`
, and such, to no avail.

The problem is not precisely the number of dimensions (nor the mix of infinite and finite limits) because if I instead formulate this as infinite integrals over the three Cartesian coordinates,

```
    NIntegrate[(Exp[(-eta1)*Sqrt[x1[1]^2 + x1[2]^2 + x1[3]^2]]/
     Sqrt[x1[1]^2 + x1[2]^2 + x1[3]^2])*(Exp[(-eta2)*
       Sqrt[(x1[1] - x2[1])^2 + (x1[2] - x2[2])^2 + (x1[3] 
       - x2[3])^2]]/Sqrt[(x1[1] - x2[1])^2 + 
       (x1[2] - x2[2])^2 + (x1[3] - x2[3])^
        2]), {x1[1], -Infinity, Infinity},  
        {x1[2], -Infinity, Infinity}, {x1[3], -Infinity, Infinity}]
         /. {eta1 -> 3, eta2 -> 5, x2[1] -> 0, x2[2] -> 0, x2[3] -> 7}
```

, I can introduce the first Gaussian transform with no problem (4-D), but the second Gaussian transform again fails (5-D),

```
    NIntegrate[((1/Sqrt[Pi])*(1/(E^(eta1^2/(4*rho1))*
    Sqrt[rho1]))*(1/Sqrt[Pi])*(1/(E^(eta2^2/(4*rho2))*
    Sqrt[rho2])))/(E^(rho1*(x1[1]^2 + x1[2]^2 + x1[3]^2))*
    E^(rho2*((x1[1] - x2[1])^2 + (x1[2] - x2[2])^2 
    + (x1[3] - x2[3])^2))), 
     {x1[1], -Infinity, Infinity}, {x1[2], -Infinity, Infinity}, 
     {x1[3], -Infinity, Infinity}, {rho1, 0, Infinity}, 
     {rho2, 0, Infinity}] /. {eta1 -> 3, eta2 -> 5, x2[1] -> 0, 
     x2[2] -> 0, x2[3] -> 7}
```

. Once I have completed the square and analytically integrated over u and r1 (or `x1[1], x1[2], and x1[3]`)the two remaining rho numerical integrals again check.
Any help untangling this puzzle would be much appreciated.  Jack

Answer (score 2):

```
expr1 = ((1/Sqrt[Pi])*(1/(E^(eta1^2/(4*rho1))*Sqrt[rho1]))*(1/
       Sqrt[Pi])*(1/(E^(eta2^2/(4*rho2))*Sqrt[rho2]))*r1^2*2*
     Pi)/(E^(rho1*r1^2)*E^(rho2*(r1^2 - 2*r1*r2*u + r2^2)));
```

Two of the integrations can be done analytically

```
expr2 = Integrate[expr1,
  {u, -1, 1}, {r1, 0, Infinity}]

(* (E^(-(eta1^2/(4 rho1)) - eta2^2/(4 rho2) - (r2^2 rho1 rho2)/(
  rho1 + rho2)) Sqrt[π])/(Sqrt[rho1] Sqrt[rho2] (rho1 + rho2)^(3/2)) *)

int = NIntegrate[
  expr2 /. {eta1 -> 3, eta2 -> 5, r2 -> 7}, {rho1, 0, Infinity}, 
   {rho2, 0, Infinity}]

(* 8.50761*10^-11 *)
```

Comment: Yes, all the integrals in this problem can be done analytically, but on more complicated problems involving more products of wave functions and such, one needs a numerical integration check to make sure that (after the integral transforms have been introduced) the completion of the square and following steps are done correctly and that no factors of Pi and 2 have been dropped.  But if the numerical integration fails in this problem, it will be useless in the harder problems.  That is why I asked for help on the errors showing up in the numerical integration in this simple case.  Thanks, Jack